# How to use bundler cache to speed up bundle install

Tags: docker, bundle

According to https://bundler.io/man/bundle-cache.1.html, you can run `bundle cache` to populate the `vendor/cache` file so that `bundle install` is much faster going forward. However, I've done that and still seem to have issues with my `Dockerfile`.

For example, here's my `vendor/cache` folder:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-20-40-151:~/rails-app$ pwd
/home/ubuntu/rails-app
ubuntu@ip-10-20-40-151:~/rails-app$ ls -l vendor/cache/
total 61212
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu    29696 Jan  7 00:34 MailchimpMarketing-3.0.72.gem
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu    41984 Jan  7 00:34 actioncable-6.1.4.4.gem
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu    22016 Jan  7 00:34 actionmailbox-6.1.4.4.gem
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu    30720 Jan  7 00:34 actionmailer-6.1.4.4.gem
...
```

and here is the part in my `Dockerfile` that runs `bundle install`:

```
WORKDIR /myapp
COPY Gemfile.lock Gemfile /myapp/
ADD vendor /myapp/
RUN bundle install --local
COPY . /myapp
```

However, whenever I run this, I get the following output from the docker build process:

```
...
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 286ab7f51c0c
Step 4/13 : WORKDIR /myapp
 ---> Using cache
 ---> cc3e7784a288
Step 5/13 : COPY Gemfile.lock Gemfile /myapp/
 ---> 2541af0e2fd8
Step 6/13 : ADD vendor /myapp/
 ---> 818c2f99e59a
Step 7/13 : RUN bundle install --local
 ---> Running in c54bc9f497cf
Could not find rails-6.1.4.4 in any of the sources
```

but `rails-6.1.4.4` exists:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-20-40-151:~/rails-app$ ls ./vendor/cache/rails-6.1.4.4.gem
./vendor/cache/rails-6.1.4.4.gem
```

What exactly am I doing wrong? Am I copying the vendor folder to the Docker image incorrectly, or am I just misunderstanding the way `bundler install` works with `bundle cache`?

My situation is extremely identical to [Using vendored gems in vendor/cache with Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62013192/using-vendored-gems-in-vendor-cache-with-docker;) however, the solution doesn't seem to the trick.

When I change my `Dockerfile` to:

```
WORKDIR /myapp
COPY Gemfile.lock Gemfile /myapp/
COPY vendor/cache /myapp/vendor/cache/
RUN bundle install --local
COPY . /myapp
```

my `bundle install` command then results in the following:

```
Installing rake 13.0.6
Installing excon 0.89.0
Installing json 2.6.1 with native extensions
Installing concurrent-ruby 1.1.9
Installing racc 1.6.0 with native extensions
Installing minitest 5.15.0
Installing zeitwerk 2.5.1
Installing builder 3.2.4
Installing erubi 1.10.0
Installing crass 1.0.6
Installing rack 2.2.3
```

Not sure if `bundle cache` is supposed to make `bundle install` faster by not fetching or by having the gems already pre-installed.